# Get property with highest value from key value pair

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In MongoDB, I have documents with a structure like this:

```
{
    _id: "123456...", // an ObjectId
    name: "foobar",
    classification: {
        class_1: 0.45,
        class_2: 0.11,
        class_3: 0.44
    }
}
```

Using the aggregation pipeline, is it possible to give me an object that contains the highest classification? So, given the above, I would like something like this as result:

```
{
    _id: "123456...", // an ObjectId
    name: "foobar",
    classification: "class_1"
}
```

I thought I could use `$unwind` but the `classification` property is not an array.

For what it's worth: I know there will always be three properties in `classification`, so it's ok to hard-code the keys in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably note here that every technique applied is essentially based on "coercion" of the "key/value" pairs into an "array" format for comparison and extraction. So the real lesson to learn is is that your document "should" in fact store this as an "array" instead. But onto the techniques.

If you have MongoDB 3.4 then you can use `$objectToArray` to turn the "keys" into an array so you can get the value:

### Dynamic

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$addFields": {
     "classification": {
       "$arrayElemAt": [
           { "$map": {
             "input": {
               "$filter": {
                 "input": { "$objectToArray": "$classification" },
                 "as": "c",
                 "cond": { 
                   "$eq": [
                     "$$c.v",
                     { "$max": {
                       "$map": {
                         "input": { "$objectToArray": "$classification" },
                         "as": "c",
                         "in": "$$c.v"
                       } 
                     }}
                   ]          
                 }
               }
             },
             "as": "c",
             "in": "$$c.k",
           }},
           0
       ]
     }
   }}
])
```

Otherwise just to the transformation as you iterate the cursor if you do not really need it for further aggregation. As a basic JavaScript example:

```
 db.collection.find().map(d => Object.assign(
   d,
   { classification: Object.keys(d.classification)
       .filter(k => d.classification[k] === Math.max.apply(null,
         Object.keys(d.classification).map(k => d.classification[k])
       ))[0]
   }
 ));
```

And that's also the same basic logic that you apply using mapReduce if you were actually aggregating something.

Both produce:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "123456...",
    "name" : "foobar",
    "classification" : "class_1"
}
```

---

### HardCoding

On the "hardcoding" case which you say is okay. Then you can construct like this with [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) by supplying  [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) with each of the values:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "classification": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "max": {
            "$max": [ 
              "$classification.class_1", 
              "$classification.class_2",
              "$classification.class_3"
            ]
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$switch": {
            "branches": [
              { "case": { "$eq": [ "$classification.class_1", "$$max" ] }, "then": "class_1" },
              { "case": { "$eq": [ "$classification.class_2", "$$max" ] }, "then": "class_2" },
              { "case": { "$eq": [ "$classification.class_3", "$$max" ] }, "then": "class_3" },               
            ] 
          }
        }   
      }
    }    
  }}
])
```

Which gives rise to then actually being able to write that out longer using [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/), and then the only real constraint is the change in [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) for MongoDB 3.2, which allowed an array of arguments as opposed to it's previous role as an "accumulator only":

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "classification": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "max": {
            "$max": [ 
              "$classification.class_1", 
              "$classification.class_2",
              "$classification.class_3"
            ]
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ "$classification.class_1", "$$max" ] },
            "then": "class_1",
            "else": {
              "$cond": {
                "if": { "$eq": [ "$classification.class_2", "$$max" ] },
                "then": "class_2",
                "else": "class_3"
              }
            }
          }
        }   
      }
    }    
  }}
])
```

If you were "really" constrained then you could "force" the `"max"` through a separate pipeline stage using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on the array then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) again. This would make the operations compatible with MongoDB 2.6:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "classification": 1,
    "max": {
      "$map": {
        "input": [1,2,3],
        "as": "e",
        "in": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ "$$e", 1 ] },
            "then": "$classification.class_1",
            "else": {
              "$cond": {
                "if": { "$eq": [ "$$e", 2 ] },
                "then": "$classification.class_2",
                "else": "$classification.class_3"    
              }
            }    
          }
        }    
      }
    }    
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$max" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "name": { "$first": "$name" },    
    "classification": { "$first": "$classification" },
    "max": { "$max": "$max" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "classification": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": { "$eq": [ "$classification.class_1", "$max" ] },
        "then": "class_1",
        "else": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ "$classification.class_2", "$max" ] },
            "then": "class_2",
            "else": "class_3"
          }
        }
      }
    }    
  }}
])
```

And going really ancient, then we can instead [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) from `$const`, which was (and still is) a "hidden" and undocumented operator equal in function to [`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) (which is technically aliased to it) in modern versions, but also with the alternate syntax to [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) as an "array" ternary operation this then becomes compatible with all versions since the aggregation framework existed:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "classification": 1,
    "temp": { "$const": [1,2,3] }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$temp" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "name": { "$first": "$name" },
    "classification": { "$first": "$classification" },
    "max": {
      "$max": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [ "$temp", 1 ] },
          "$classification.class_1",
          { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$temp", 2 ] },
            "$classification.class_2",
            "$classification.class_3"    
          ]}
        ]     
      }
    }    
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "classification": {
      "$cond": [
        { "$eq": [ "$max", "$classification.class_1" ] },
        "class_1",
        { "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [ "$max", "$classification.class_2" ] },
          "class_2",
          "class_3"   
        ]} 
      ] 
    }   
  }}
])
```

But it is of course possible, even if extremely messy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$indexOfArray` operator to find the `$max` value in `classification` followed by projecting the key. `$objectToArray` to convert `classification` embedded doc into array of key value pairs in 3.4.4 version.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      "$addFields": {
        "classification": {
          "$let": {
            "vars": {
              "classificationkv": {
                "$objectToArray": "$classification"
              }
            },
            "in": {
              "$let": {
                "vars": {
                  "classificationmax": {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$$classificationkv",
                      {
                        "$indexOfArray": [
                          "$$classificationkv.v",
                          {
                            "$max": "$$classificationkv.v"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "in": "$$classificationmax.k"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went with a more simple solution, but not as generic as the other ones posted here. I used this a switch case statement:

```
{'$project': {'_id': 1, 'name': 1,
              'classification': {'$switch': {
                  'branches': [
                      {'case': {'$and': [{'$gt': ['$classification.class_1', '$classification.class_2']},
                                         {'$gt': ['$classification.class_1', '$classification.class_3']}]},
                           'then': "class1"},
                      {'case': {'$and': [{'$gt': ['$classification.class_2', '$classification.class_1']},
                                         {'$gt': ['$classification.class_2', '$classification.class_3']}]},
                           'then': "class_2"},
                      {'case': {'$and': [{'$gt': ['$classification.class_3', '$classification.class_1']},
                                         {'$gt': ['$classification.class_3', '$classification.class_2']}]},
                           'then': "class_3"}],
                      'default': ''}}
                  }}
```

This works for me, but the other answers might be a better option, YMMV.